# Jupyter not importing python module

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Anaconda for windows 10, and I want to import some older notebooks from Docker. I installed tweepy in a new eviroment with Anaconda Prompt

```
conda install -c conda-forge tweepy
```

and checked in the command line with import tweepy

I have remained in the new environment named "twitter_api", in Anaconda Prompt, and switched to this env in Anaconda Navigator. Here I installed Jupiter Notebooks and copied the old notes in a new folder. But when I am trying to run them, an error appears:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy'
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a menu option in Anaconda Navigator in Environments tab that reads

> Open with Jupiter Notebook